# Android volley library is not accepting parameters in url from getParam()

Tags: android, string, web-services, request, android-volley

Android volley library is not accepting parameters from getParam() method.If it is given in query String then it works.I tried both GET and POST it doesn't works. But I want to give parameters POST Method.please check the code I have posted below.

```html
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
  String url = AppConstants.WEBSERVICE_URL
    + AppConstants.WEBSERVICE_URL_POST_COMMENT;

  StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {

     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {
      // response
      Log.d("Response_postComment", response);
 
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        ReviewActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("serviceId", servicePosition);
      startActivity(intent);
     }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      // error
      Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
     }
    }) {
    
   
   @Override
             public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                 Map<String, String> pars = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 pars.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                 return pars;
             }
   
   @Override
   protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("rating", ratingBar.getRating() + "");
    params.put("com_content", comments.getText() + "");
    params.put("user_id", AppConstants.APP_LOGIN_USER_ID);
    params.put("comm_post_ID", AppConstants.arrListServiceDetail
      .get(servicePosition).getId() + "");

    return params;
   }
  };

  getRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(500000,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
  queue.add(getRequest);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "volley library is not accepting parameters from getParam()" Is the getParams() method is not getting called or the returned parameters are not included in the post body even the getParams() method called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getParam() method not working with GET request on volley.its working fine with POST methods.you have to set up complete URL with parameters.

Comment: I tried in post also with same code..but it is not working :(

Comment: As you told it worked when i tried second time..I dont know the reason but the same above code worked by changing GET to POST...thanks

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue as you are facing now, but comes up with solution of making a custom request by making the core class Request as the super class of this request. In this i am passing params in constructor, then returning it to the getParams() overridden method as below:

```
public class RequestJson extends Request<JSONObject> {

private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
private Map<String, String> params;

public RequestJson(String url, Map<String, String> params,
        Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

public RequestJson(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
        Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    return params;
};

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    AppController.getInstance().checkSessionCookie(response.headers);
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listener.onResponse(response);
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

    if (headers == null
            || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    AppController.getInstance().addSessionCookie(headers);

    return headers;
}
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: my problem solved, but thanks for suggestion.I have used String Request will it work for String request??

Comment: yes, its also works well by overriding the  string request as same.

Comment: you can override the same as above example, and let me know if its solved your problem.

Comment: ok if required I will try this..and let you know whether it works or not.if you try then also let me know whether it works or not...